# Goodstein's theorem without transfinite induction

Tags: reference-request, logic, proof-theory

Is it possible to prove [Goodstein's theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Goodstein%27s_theorem)  without transfinite induction? Is there such a proof?

Comment: You might in general be interested in *reverse mathematics*, which studies the amount of induction (and other axioms) needed in many theorems.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'm pretty sure the short answer is "no" (if you mean, can you prove Goodstein's theorem without invoking apparatus as strong as a transfinite induction which can't be reduced to an ordinary induction). For if I recall correctly, Goodstein's theorem is actually equivalent (over a weak base theory) to transfinite induction up to $\varepsilon_0$. My first port of call to check this would be Kirby and Paris's paper on 'Accessible independence results for Peano Arithmetic'.

Comment: I can't tell if you are just being modest, but the phrasing of your reply suggests some uncertainty. If so, please let me assure you that I believe that your answer is exactly correct.

Answer (score 0):

I found the following paper which seems fairly relevant:

> Miller J.T. **[On the independence of Goodstein’s theorem](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.72.8407&rep=rep1&type=pdf)**. 2001, Citeseer.

Comment: @rank: Look at the section about the independence itself. This means that you cannot prove the theorem from first-order PA without some extra assumptions, which are ultimately equivalent to the transfinite induction.